# upload dialog issues - safari 5.0.5

Tags: jquery-plugins, file-upload, cross-browser, safari

I am using file-upload plugin - blue-imp.
Testing the demo page in Safari 5.0.5 (Windows XP), when you click "add files", the upload dialog appears but is not clickable at first. Then, if you select a file, the click goes right through the dialog as if it weren't visible. The next click is caught by the dialog, but if you select a file and click "open", the dialog closes and reopens instantly. You then may "cancel" or select another file. The latter consequently uploads two files.

As there is a native browser UI element involved, I suppose jQuery-File-Upload triggers a bug in Safari 5.0.5 (Windows).

Are there any workarounds to avoid this behaviour?

I have commented out following line in file `jquery.fileupload.js` under function  `_replaceFileInput`

```
input.after(inputClone).detach();
```

This have resolved the problem of file dialog that appears after selection of file , but unable to understand the logic behind , can anybody explain it to me ?